# Как передать класс по клику в другой компонент?

Tags: vue.js, vue3

Подскажите пожалуйста у меня есть компонент TableControl.vue, вешается клик @click="sortOpen" для открытия окна, мне нужно передать класс в другой компонент TableTamplate

```html
                <tr class="sticky bg-black-900 top-0 z-10 h-10" :class="{'relative' : sortOpen}"
```

но не срабатывает, объясните пожалуйста пробывал через $emit, но не могу понять как пробросить клик. Спасибо заранее

Comment: А что непонятного в $emit? Генерируете событие, а выше его по @имени и выполняете функцию

Comment: @VladimirGonchar, а можно пожалуйста на примере показать ? Был бы очень признателен.